# Ferrite bead on a SMPS output

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, linear-regulator, ferrite-bead

Suppose I have an instrument which needs a very clean power supply line. I have an SMPS which outputs 24 V at 3.2 A, which is then cleaned via a LM1084 linear regulator.

Given that the output of a SMPS usually is considerably noisy (noise spikes and nonlinear ripple), would it be prudent to include a ferrite bead between the SMPS and the linear regulator to suppress HF noise? Or is the regulation provided by the LM1084 enough for a clean supply?

Comment: What ripple is acceptable?  Are some frequencies more problematic than others?  What is the ripple characteristic of your supply?

Comment: First of all, not all switching regulators are noisy. A properly designed one can have really low ripple, or at least acceptably low for your application. The spikes you mention can be not real spikes but those visible due to poor/wrong probing. The bead-capacitor filter will work for DM noise, so if your regulator is an off-line SMPS with PE (earth) connection (primary only) and if your load has a PE connection as well then you may see the CM noise on your load. Also, if your load draws pulsating currents then having bead on the supply rail may cause more trouble than it'll possibly solve.

Comment: @vir ripple is 150mVp-p for the LRS-75-24. I would preferably like to limit this to >75mVp-p or lower.

Comment: @lemon 30-40mVpp ripple is easily achievable with a switching regulator to begin with. If you really need a clean supply, ferrite bead may not do anything and you should try LC or RC filter.

Comment: How much current does your load consume?

Comment: What are your ripple requirments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some notes:

If your 24V load contains buck DC-DC converters to generate its internal power rails, or other noise makers like high current loads with PWM... it will generate a considerable amount of high frequency noise on the 24V input. Thus spending extra to feed it clean power is a waste of components. In fact, if a wall wart is used, the purpose of the input CLC filter in the device being powered is often to prevent noise from internal buck converters from radiating via the power cable...

High-current "low noise" power supplies are often a XY problem. If your load draws varying current (and if you use a 3.2A supply I'm pretty sure it will) then the output of your power supply will have ripple and noise due to load current variations and finite output impedance. This is unavoidable. The only way to have a perfectly clean power supply is to power something that draws constant current, like a clock oscillator.

Thus a targeted approach is often a lot more effective: find the thing in the circuit that is sensitive to noise (maybe some opamps, or a voltage reference) and add a good filter there. Since it will operate on a much lower current, you can get much better filtering more easily. Then find the thing that makes the most noise, and make it a quieter with a filter on the input, or other countermeasures.

For example if you have a class D audio amp, this will dump a ton of noise into the power supply. But the part that is sensitive to noise is just the input opamps, the error amp and modulator, in other words, maybe 10mA at 5-15V. So it's easy to design a very effective filter just for this.

Now on to the question: LM1084 PSRR according to datasheet:

[image]

The first thing to do would be to characterize the ripple/noise on your power supply at the expected load current. You can use a spectrum analyzer, or a scope in FFT mode, or just eyeball the screen. Take note of noise in three frequency bands:

- Low (<10kHz)
- Medium (10kHz-1MHz)
- High (>1MHz)

In the low band, if your switching power supply is competent there should be very little ripple and noise, unless the load is using low power and the supply enters a power-saving mode where it will go into cycles of burst then sleep or skip cycles, resulting in sawtooth ripple at much lower frequency than the usual switching frequency.

PSRR of LM1084 is very good in the low frequency band, so it will clean it up.

When looking at the PSRR plot in a datasheet, note that it very often includes the output cap, especially if the LDO requires one and can't be tested without it.

Medium band is the SMPS' switching frequency and harmonics. Linear regulators have falling PSRR with frequency so they're not usually very effective in this band. So you can use a LC filter. It should be well damped (usually by the capacitor's ESR). These filters usually employ electrolytic caps due to the large values required. The inductor will need to be quite high value and your current is also rather high, which means the inductor will be large, with many turns, thus high inter-winding capacitance and low self resonance frequency. In other words, the inductor will turn into a cap somewhere above 1MHz, and the capacitor, being large too, will turn into an inductor at a similar frequency. This means it will not be effective in the High band.

The high band contains switching spikes and their harmonics which extend very high. At this point, your LDO is a capacitor, so these go straight through. To clean this up you also need a LC filter, but with a low inductance cap (SMD MLCC) and an inductor that remains inductive at high frequency. Ferrite beads are ideal for this due to their dissipative nature. You should be careful to select one that will not saturate at your rated current.

Your SMPS may or may not already contain a LC filter at the output.

Filters should be placed before the LDO, otherwise they add up to the output impedance.

Comment: 'ferrite beads are ideal for this due to their dissipative nature', why would you choose a ferrite bead over an inductor for an LC filter? Looking at datasheets only gives you a maximum current rating and its impedance over frequency.

Comment: Because ferrite bead material is optimized for this kind of filtering, they're very lossy, at high frequency they become resistive which turns noise into heat, and impedance remains high up to hundreds of MHz or even GHz. Also cheap. Inductors are better at lower frequency due to higher inductance.

Comment: Here's an example https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/ABRACON/ALFB-02?qs=7Oetya%252B4D2AjOZV13jb20A%3D%3D

Comment: so ferrite beads turn noise into heat with increasing frequency. wouldn't this instigate power loss due to its increasing resistance?

Comment: It would be a bad idea to use a ferrite bead in a circuit where you need an inductor with low loss at high frequency, like in a radio tuning circuit. Ferrite beads having high loss at high frequency is a feature: in your filter you want DC to pass with minimum loss (low DC resistance) but HF noise is not useful power for your load.

Answer (score 0):

A ferrite bead typically starts suppressing noise at frequencies >30MHz, whereas  SMPSs typically operate at <1.5 MHz frequencies. Therefore a ferrite bead is not your first choice for noise suppression of SMPS ripples.

The LM1074 has a ripple rejection of 75dB, so the LM1074 attenuates the ripples from the SMPS by a factor of ~5620.

Depending on your requirements, this might be OK for you.